# How to share opaque type across multiple translation units?

Tags: c, linux, struct

I'm working on my own C-project and need some design/common_C_idiom advice. The problem I'm trying to solve is to open an input date stream of a configured device. But I want to keep configuration and device separated. Here is what I tried:

1. Configuration:

`config.h`

```
#ifndef CONFIG_H
#define CONFIG_H

typedef struct config_t config_t;

config_t* config_t_allocate(void);
void config_t_free(config_t *);
//functions to set configuration parameters

#endif //CONFIG_H
```

`config.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "device.h"

struct config_t{
    const char * name;
};

config_t* config_t_allocate(void){
    return malloc(sizeof(config_t));
}

void config_t_free(config_t * config_ptr){
    free(config_ptr);
}
```

2. Device:

`device.h`

```
#ifndef DEVICE_H
#define DEVICE_H

typedef struct config_t config_t;

typedef struct device_t device_t;

void configure_device(device_t**, config_t*);

//other device-related methods

#endif //DEVICE_H
```

`device.c`

```
#include "device.h"
#include <sys/fcntl.h>

struct device_t{
    int fd;
};

//Does not compile. What is the confit_t type?
void configure_device(device_t** device, config_t* config_ptr){
    *device = malloc(sizeof(**device));
    (*device) -> fd = open(config_ptr -> name, O_RDONLY);
}
```

So I would like to share the `config_t` type completed in `config.c` across multiple translation units. The only thing I can imagine is to create a ***"private"*** header file containg the struct. Something like this:
`types/configdef.h`

```
#ifndef TYPES_CONFIG_DEF_H
#define TYPES_CONFIG_DEF_H

struct config_t{
    const char * name;
};

#endif //TYPES_CONFIG_DEF_H
```

And include it everywhere I need the `config_t`.

Comment: Include the `config.h` header file wherever you need the `config_t` type.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But it does not contain the actual struct definition. Do not quite understand.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The thing is the `struct config_t{ const chat * name; }` is defined in `config.c`. I thought it is not a good idea to put this definition into `config.h` and go about opaque type.

Comment: Maybe this just means the API in `config.h` is far from being minimal and complete. Your problem is nothing unique to C, just a sign of potentially undue coupling.

Comment: strongly suggest moving: `struct config_t{
    const char * name;
};` from its' current location to the `config.h` header file

Comment: @StoryTeller In terms of building the config using some parameters it is. But yes, maybe it would make sense to move everything here to a single header file.

Comment: @user3629249 Why? Does not it introduce a coupling to the fact that the `config_t` consists from a single `const char *` parameter?

Comment: If you use an opaque type like `config_t`, you forgo the option of accessing its members directly in the source code that isn't privy to the implementation details.  You could provide a function to do that, though: `extern char *config_t_get_name(config_t *config);` or thereabouts, declared in `config.h`, defined in `config.c`, used in `device.c`.  The alternative is, indeed, a 'private' header, but that's not as good as an access function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler But how about putting `struct config_t{ const char * name; };` into some header file which I will not expose (sort of library private) and using it everywhere in implementation `c` files. Isn't it common or have some drawbacks?

Comment: It can be done; it is not entirely uncommon, especially if the suite of functions that need access to the internals of the structure is too large to fit sanely in a single source file (or because local rules are 'one function per source file', or …). The difficulty, then, is ensuring that files that should not be privy to the private header cannot (do not) use it.  That suggests that the private header should not be installed with the library, and possibly the private header should be in a separate directory from the public header(s) for the project.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Understood. Thanks much!

Comment: I believe I already saw this. (Might have been GTK+). There are `private` directories containing the header files with types/functions which shall be shared inside of library. These are not part of the API i.e. not delivered and, hence, not available for outside code / application programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use an opaque type like `config_t`, you forgo the option of accessing its members directly in the source code that isn't privy to the implementation details. You could provide a function to do that, though:

```
extern const char *config_t_get_name(config_t *config);
```

or thereabouts, declared in `config.h`, defined in `config.c`, used in `device.c`.

> But how about putting `struct config_t{ const char * name; };` into some header file which I will not expose (sort of library private) and using it everywhere in implementation C files. Isn't it common or does it have some drawbacks?

The primary alternative to access functions is, indeed, a 'private' header, but that's usually not as good as access functions.   It can be done; it is not entirely uncommon, especially if the suite of functions that need access to the internals of the structure is too large to fit sanely in a single source file (or because local rules are 'one non-static function per source file', or …). The difficulty, then, is ensuring that files that should not be privy to the private header cannot (do not) use it. That suggests that the private header should not be installed with the library, and possibly the private header should be in a separate directory from the public header(s) for the project.

Consider whether you should enforce:

```
 #include "project/headerX.h"             // General, public headers for the project
 #include "project/private/internal.h"    // Private headers for limited use
```

You can then police the use of the private headers by using `grep` or equivalent to find references that should not be allowed, etc.  Alternatively, or perhaps in conjunction, use a distinctive naming scheme for private headers, using the `pvt_` prefix to denote 'private':

```
#include "project/internal/pvt_config.h"
```

There are endless variations on the theme.  Programmers will devise all sorts of schemes to gain access to private headers to make use of them.  Ultimately, you have to trust your programmers to obey the rules — thou shalt not use private headers except in files explicitly granted permission to use them.  If they cannot accept that discipline, maybe they shouldn't be on the project after all.  Or maybe you should take time to understand why the recalcitrant programmers cannot use the access functions you provide — is there something wrong with the design?

You might search on Google (or your search engine of choice) for '`getters setters`'; the results seem to be informative.  Add your language of choice (C++, Java, JavaScript figure prominently; C not so prominently but it does pull up references that would probably be helpful).

Comment: One trick is include public headers from h files and private headers from c files. That way you block the contents of that private header to spread across other translation units.

Comment: @Lundin You mean just to place the actual struct implementation into `c`-file. But do I need to compile it in that case or just include?

Comment: @St.Antario: I think Lundin is suggesting that only C source files from the privileged sections of the project should contain `#include` lines for private headers — they should never be included by another header file.  By contrast, the public headers for the project can be included from other headers, or from unprivileged source code (or from privileged source code, I think — but I'm not certain since I'm not Lundin).